# How do I convert multiple WAB to OFR including subdirectories?

Tags: batch-file, wav, subdirectory

I have about 2,000 WAV files which need to be converted to **optimfrog** format (OFR).

I usually use the following command for a single directory:

```
ofr --encode --maximumcompression *.wav
```

However, there are 2 main folders and several hundred sub-directories.

This will take forever manually so I am looking for an automated batch file to do this.

I have looked at the many examples and tried several but am not a programmer and am struggling to find a working version.

At some point I would need to reverse the process and use:

```
ofr --decode *.ofr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I convert multiple `wav` to `ofr` including subdirectories?

`for /r` command can be used to recursively visit all the directories in a directory tree and perform a command.

**Encode.cmd:**

```
@echo off
rem start in the current directory (the top of the tree to visit) and loop though each directory
for /r %%a in (.) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  rem perform the required command.
  ofr --encode --maximumcompression *.wav 
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )
```

**Decode.cmd:**

```
@echo off
rem start in the current directory (the top of the tree to visit) and loop though each directory
for /r %%a in (.) do (
  rem enter the directory
  pushd %%a
  rem perform the required command.
  ofr --decode *.ofr 
  rem leave the directory
  popd
  )
```

---

#### Further reading:

- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) - Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command.
- [popd](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) - Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.

Comment: Sorry, just not following you. Directory of Root is D:\Black Mesa. There are 2 sub directories, 1 is hl2 and other is BMS. within these then are dozens of sub directories in each folder. Could you please give me a layman layout for this??? Many, many thanks

Comment: @SteveRobathan What exactly are you not following? Create `Encode.cmd` in `D:\Black Mesa`, Open a `cmd` prompt. `cd /d D:\Black Mesa`, run `Encode.cmd`

Comment: @SteveRobathan The `for` loop walks the directory tree, starting at the top and visits each subdirectory in turn. As it visits it runs `ofr`. So the `ofr` command is run in every subdirectory.

Comment: I am getting OFR is not recognised as an internal or external command even though it is present with Encode.cmd just created

Comment: @SteveRobathan Either add `D:\Black Mesa` to your `PATH` or edit `encode.cmd` and replace `ocr` with `D:\Black Mesa\ocr`.

Comment: @SteveRobathan [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342)

Comment: Got it working now. Just added 2 lines to beginning of batch: SET path=%CD%
then SET path=%path:\=\\%